# Override e4 rcp keybindings

Tags: java, eclipse, e4, xmi

I'm trying to override e4 keybindings like change the behavior of "Ctrl+N" to an other action but still have conflicts.
I found that I have to use this tag "type:user", but it dosen't work for me.

e4 keybindings:
[image: e4 keybindings]

If someone can see what am I missing to have the expected behavior, I will be happy to read it.

Comment: 'type:user' is only used if you are using the 3.x compatability mode plug-in `org.eclipse.ui.workbench`. Is your Binding Context actually active?

Comment: ow ok! yes some of keybindings work correctly. e.g: M1+9 but not M1+S, and M1+N open the eclipse dialog "New". in parallel I'm trying to create an add-on "not sure it will work, in progress..."

Comment: I confirm that add-on dosen't work, "I'm on a Model Fragment". so return to scratch. Thx Greg for responding, my Binding Context is active yes.

Comment: Hello everyone, I'm desperate behind my screen because of this problem, which is amazing is that there is no concrete solution, or that I can not find it on the net...